# Is there a way to import to a Freeform Form?

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a way to import to Freeform Forms?  I wanted to create a form with pre-filled information, and users can login and use freeform edit their existing entries?

Thanks and I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Is the initial data added by the user as a Freeform entry? If it is then Freeform has the ability to restrict editing by the author - see http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/edit/#restrict_edit_to_author

Comment: I wonder if ExpressionEngine Channel Forms would be a better fit here? You could add the appropriate fields and then use something like DataGrab to import into that new channel? http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab + http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it would require some knowledge about MySQL and your form fields. Steps below:

1. Create your form in `EE CP > Add-Ons > Modules > Freeform Pro`
2. Note the newly created Freeform `form_id` (open the form page and look at your URL - you will see in the GET request the `&form_id=XX` where `XX` is an integer.
3. Open MySQL from the command line
4. Select your database. My EE db is called `expression_engine`, so I would type `use expression_engine` at the command line.
5. If you type `show tables` you will see all your EE database tables. Your Freeform form will have the table name `exp_freeform_form_entries_XX` where `XX` is your `form_id`
6. Take a look at the Freeform form table schema by typing `describe exp_freeform_form_entries_XX`. You will see all the fields and their types. An example below:

```
mysql> describe exp_freeform_form_entries_1;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| entry_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| site_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| author_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| complete     | varchar(1)       | NO   |     | y       |                |
| ip_address   | varchar(40)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| entry_date   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| edit_date    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| status       | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| form_field_1 | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| form_field_2 | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| form_field_3 | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| form_field_4 | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `author_id` field is your EE member/user primary key (the `member_id` in the `exp_members` database table). The `form_field_X` fields are your custom form fields created in Freeform. Be careful to match them up correctly! You should make sure the `entry_date` field is filled out with a valid [UNIX timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/).

Now you have all the critical fields ids you need to write a simple PHP or shell script that would run a sequence of MySQL `INSERT` statements to add your pre-filled information to the form.

I hope that helps, and good luck!